# publish ios app without any registered device

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, publish, udid

I have completed an ios app that I want to get published. I do not have any apple devices other than my mac. I used the simulator to test my app. I tried to make a provisioning profile   in the member center and link it up to my app but Xcode keeps telling me that it cannot find any compatible provisioning profiles since I do not have any ios devices registered in the member center. I believe that I cannot register my mac as an ios device. I tried doing that in the member center using my mac's UDID but it did not recognize the UDID.

I want to know if there is any way I can still have the app published without buying any other ios device?

Comment: Using only the Simulator is not an adequate test to ensure that an app will run properly on an iOS device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used the simulator to test my app.

Then you **did not test your app**. The simulator is useful but it is nowhere near an adequate substitute for device testing. What if users report that the app crashes on their devices, but you can't reproduce the crash in the simulator? This is not a hypothetical scenario, it's actually quite common.

> I want to know if there is any way I can still have the app published without buying any other ios device?

Possibly, but it would be extremely unwise to publish the app without testing it on a device. If you can't get a device, try to borrow one.

Answer (score 1):

I see only workaround here - Get device from your friend or family and register it for first install. You just need its UDID to register.